# Parse .strings file with Python

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, core-foundation

I'm trying to write a small Python script to parse the .strings file in my iPhone application project and determine which keys might not be in use. I'm, also doing some string matching to filter out some of the results. This is where my problems start :). If I try something like

```
for file_line in strings_file:    
    if 'search_keyword' in file_line:
        ...
```

the search keyword will often not match, even though if I print every file line in the same for I seem to be reading the text correctly and my search keywords appear.

The problem is these .strings files are in some binary format. Does anyone know of a proper way to parse these files?

Comment: Can you post an example .strings file?

Comment: They are pretty standard in format. I have lines like: "Keyword" = "Value"; or "Keyword" = 0.0; The files are correct as far as they're concerned. I use them from Objective-C and I have no problems there. It's just that there I use some framework provided class to open them which I probably can't use from Python

Comment: So how do you open the file? What does printing the repr() of a line you think should match show you?

Comment: I open it with open(filename, 'r'). Also tried 'U'. 'b' is not supported on Mac OS

Comment: It just occurred to me I might be able to use PyObjC to use the Objective-C code that reads these files. I'm still open to simpler solutions though

Comment: it's interesting to know that python script can be combined together in an iphone application :-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use correct encoding to open the `.strings`-file and in your [source code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html) the encoding of your file could be utf-16.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs

for line in codecs.open(u'your_file.strings', encoding='utf-16'):
    if u'keyword' in line:
       # process line
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Using your solution I realized some of my .strings were encoded utf-8 and most were utf-16. This probably explains why the matching worked only in some of the files.

Answer (score 2):

No experience with those `.strings` files, but here is the reason why you don't find matches:

```
strings_file.read()
```

returns a *string* with the full content of the file. Iterating over a string iterates over *single characters*, i.e. in your `for` loop, `file_line` isn't a line, it's always just one single character (a string of length 1), which obviously can't contain a multi-character search word.

Comment: Indeed. Use `for line in strings_file:` instead.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I was using simply for file_line in strings_file:, without the read(); will edit in a moment

Comment: @MihaiD: `for line in file` will only work (as expected) on plain text files, which (as you say) the `.strings` files are not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the stings file was saved as data. If python can't read it as is you can convert it to a plain text file in Objective-c.

Just: (1) read the strings file into a file with the proper encoding. (2) Convert to dictionary (3) write dictionary to another file.

So:

```
NSString *strings=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict=[strings propertyList];
[dict writeToFile:anotherFilePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Yes, that's one way to go. Will keep in mind if all else fails.